# Dynamic deletion from SQL database for .NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dynamic, sql-delete

I have a SQL database that store values input via a text box. This then displays the values of that database on my output screen via a gridbox. Is there a way I can give the user the an option of which column he wants to delete? Like a delete button near the value in the gridbox.

If not how do I delete a variable column number in SQL. Like, If the user wants to delete line say 10. How do I incorporate that in my SQL delete command.

Should it incorporate the  'top' command? If so how?

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();

    sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=abc; Initial Catalog=VisualStudioTest; User ID=USER; Password=PASS");
    sc.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = sc;
    com.CommandText = ("delete from notes");//initially I've kept this to delete everything.

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sc.Close();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VisualStudioTestConnectionString3 %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Notes] FROM [Notes]" 
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Never delete a record based on it's index... If you want to delete a specific record, do it using it's primary key.

Comment: Is this SQL Server, and which version? Please add the tags accordingly !

Answer (score 0):

i assume your goal is to delete a single row.

the simplest way that comes to my mind is to add a identity field as a key for the table, add the new column to the `DataKeyNames` list of the `GridView` and then add a parameter to the `DeleteQuery` in the `SqlDataSource`:

```
delete from notes where identityCol = @identityCol;
```

the last step is to add the delete control to the `Gridview`.